# How to dynamic output a file content with replaced some bytes?

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic, zip, fuse

> I used a fuse plugin named '[concatfs](https://github.com/schlaile/concatfs)'
>
> It can virtual merge some file with a specific filename like `xxx-concat-.mkv`, 
>   and this file's content is a **TEXT**:

```
1.mkv
2.mkv
3.mkv
```

> system reads `xxx-concat-.mkv`, it **outputs** a merged file with `1.mkv 2.mkv ...`. but the files are not merged in fact, it's a virtual output.

So, My question is :

- a static file, 1.zip > 300 MB.
- It has so many copies(publish to many people), and the difference is only 4 bytes `offset: 0xa 0xb 0xc 0xd` in these copies. the 4 bytes is people's id
- so I wanna make a file named '1-replaced-123.zip' like `concatfs`, content mostly like:(all binary)

> 1.zip
>
> 0xa 4 replaced-4bytes-binary-content
>
> 0x1111 10 replaced-10bytes-binary-content

- system reads `1-replaced-123.zip`, the `fuse` will outputing the replaced content.
- It can saves so many disk space.
- And I known PHP/JSP can read and echo with replaced, but php will using a high cpu/memory to echo big file stream.

do you have some suggestion?

> Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english.

Comment: 14 views, 2 down-votes,Why down-vote? I donot understand. What problem with the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **merged-fuse** to virtual merge/replace files (C++ 11)

https://github.com/fly-studio/merged-fuse

**Example**

1.txt

```
12345678
```

2.txt

```
abcdefghi
```

Make a file named `1-merged-.txt`,

`-merged-` is a special words in the file name

content is JSON format

```
[
    {
        "path": "1.txt"
    },
    {
        "path": "2.txt",
        "replaces": [
             {
                 "offset": 2,
                 "length": 2,
                 "content": "MjE="
             }
        ]
    }
]
```

When `cat 1-merged-.txt`, output:

```
12345678ab12efghi
```

You can see the files were merged(virtual), and the content was replaced:

`cd` replaced to `12`